# Bandwidth of PXIE-6738

Tags: analog, bandwidth

Hope this is the right forum.

I can't find the explicit bandwidth of this analog output module: [PXIE-6738](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/pxie-6738-specs/page/specs.html) from National Instruments. In the data sheet there are two specifications that may be relevant, but I don't know which I should take into account:

The maximum update rate:

- 1 channel: 1 MS/s
- 8 channels (1 channel per bank):1 MS/s
- 32 channels: 350 kS/s

or the inverse of the settling time (maybe \$ \times 2 \pi\$  ):

- 15 µs to ±4 LSB

Which is the right one ? neither ?

Comment: No experience with this specific device, but on other NI hardware the bandwidth is often significantly higher than the Nyquist rate, and you need to add your own reconstruction filter if you want to reject image frequencies, so good chance that is the case here.